# Manipulation of a statement containing a real variable and an integer variable

Tags: real-analysis, induction, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

Suppose you have a statement $P(x,n)$ that's true for all reals $x$ and integers $n$, would this imply that $P(n,n)$ is true for all integers $n$?

For example, the Bernoulli's inequality usually states that $(1 + x)^n\geq 1 + nx$ for all real numbers $x\geq-1$ and all integers $n\geq 0$. To prove it, one may fix $x$, and then proceed it by induction on $n$. Now, the question is, is it allowed to let $x=n$, i.e. does it imply that $(1 + n)^n\geq 1 + n^2$ for all integers $n\geq 0$? If yes, why? (It may seem obvious, but not to me.)

Comment: If a statement is true for all elements in a set S, it is true for all elements in a subset A of S.

Comment: @JoelPereira So, what you are saying is just by letting $x$ to belong to the set of non-negative integers, and thus letting $x=n$ is permissible/possible?

Comment: yes. If you're unsure, let x = n and go through the induction proof and convince yourself that the statement is true.

Comment: @JoelPereira That's what I've tried: I can't show that $(1+(k+1))^{k+1}\geq 1+(k+1)^2$ with the property that $(1+k)^{k}\geq 1+k^2$. There is no way to expand $(1+(k+1))^{k+1}$ by hand without using the binomial theorem. That's why I asked here to see if it's okay to put $x=n$ just to save energy.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor No need to use the binomial theorem to expand $(1+(k+1))^{k+1}$. It can be written $(1+(k+1))^k\cdot (1+k+1)$. The first factor is at least $(1+k)^k$, which by induction hypothesis is at least $1+k^2$. So the product of these two factors is at least $(1+k^2)(2+k)=2+k+2k+k^3$ which is at least $1+(k+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

As you know, an integer is a real.

so, if some predicate is true for all reals, it will be true, in particular, for all integers.

Thus
$$\forall (x,n)\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb N \;\;  P(x,n) \implies $$
$$\forall (m,n)\in \Bbb N^2 \;\;  P(m,n)$$

what about the case $m=n$.